# python asyncio and errorhandling

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, python-asyncio

I have the following example for errorhandling with asyncio:

```
import asyncio
import logging


def handle_exception(loop, context):
    msg = context.get("exception", context["message"])
    logging.error(f"Caught exception: {msg}")
    logging.warning("Shutting down...")
    asyncio.create_task(shutdown(loop))


async def shutdown(loop, signal=None):
    """Cleanup tasks tied to the service's shutdown."""
    if signal:
        logging.warning(f"Received exit signal {signal.name}...")
    tasks = [t for t in asyncio.all_tasks() if t is not
             asyncio.current_task()]
    [task.cancel() for task in tasks]
    logging.warning(f"Cancelling {len(tasks)} outstanding tasks")
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    loop.stop()


async def bug():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    raise ValueError("some error")


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_exception_handler(handle_exception)

    try:
        loop.create_task(bug())
        loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        loop.close()
        logging.warning("shutdown completed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works for me with this "lower level function". But i don't get how to do it without lower level functions.
If i try this (rest of the code is the same as above):

```
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_exception_handler(handle_exception)

    asyncio.create_task(bug())
    await asyncio.sleep(20)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

i always get an asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

How to do this with asyncio.run ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `CancelledError` because `asyncio.run` (like `loop.run_until_complete`, but unlike `loop.run_forever`) runs a particular coroutine, and returns its result. When the coroutine is cancelled, the "result" is a `CancelledError` exception, so that's what `asyncio.run()` raises. If that doesn't work for you, you can just handle the exception either in `main()` or in the code that invokes `asyncio.run()`. For example:

```
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_exception_handler(handle_exception)
    asyncio.create_task(bug())
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        logging.warning("main cancelled")
```

Also, when using `asyncio.run()`, you shouldn't call `loop.stop()` in `shutdown`. Stopping the event loop is not allowed when using `asyncio.run` or `loop.run_until_complete` and will result in a runtime error complaining of "Event loop stopped before Future completed." The only reason your code *doesn't* provoke this error is that the main task gets cancelled, so `main()` gets to complete before the loop stops.